# Custom separator for CSV import via csvsimple

Tags: pgfkeys, import, csv, csvsimple

I have successfully used csvsimple to import .csv files. But I would like to have commas as number separators, so I modified the .csv file to use semicolons as separators and as csvsimple manual says, I defined it with `separator=semicolon` like this

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c c|c}%
  & \bfseries A & \bfseries B & \\\hline
  \csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\, separator=semicolon]%
  {csv/test.csv}{}%
  {\bfseries\cat & \A & \B & \acc\%}%
\end{tabular}
```

but I keep getting error
`! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/csv/separator' and I am going to ignore it.`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.sx. Can you please turn this into a complete compilable document that produces the error. When I construct such an example, it works.

Comment: What version of `csvsimple` are you using? According to the [CHANGES](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/CHANGES) file, `separator` was introduced in version 1.07.

Comment: `Package: csvsimple 2012/11/08 version 1.06 LaTeX CSV file processing.` you are right. I knew, that the version is quite new from last year, but I didn't realize that Ubuntu 13.10 has older versions in repositories... thanks

Answer (score 4):

I used `/csv/separator=semicolon` instead of `separator=semicolon` and it worked.

Comment: Please add a compilable MWE for an easy proof of the op.  That's the usual way here to make an good answer.  Welcome!

Comment: Thank you. But I don't get it, can you explain?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
a1;b1;c1;d1
a2; "b21 and b22";c2;d2
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[
  noheader,
  keys={A,B,C,D}
  ]{mydb}{mydata.csv}
%=======
\begin{document}
%=======

\DTLforeach*{mydb}{\A=A,\B=B,\C=C,\D=D}{
  \section{\A}
\begin{tabular}{c|c c|c}%
  & \bfseries \A & \bfseries \B & \\\hline
   \bfseries \C & Y & Z 
\end{tabular}
 }
%=======
\end{document}
%=======
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which deals with the `csvsimple` package, not `datatool`.  Since both are fine packages, it's not clear that suggesting someone switch is really appropriate.